# Grid.mvc - column with ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I am trying to add a column to a grid in my ASP.net MVC 5 project that should hold list of tags* (which use ICollection).

Normally when adding a table I would use `@foreach(var item in item.Tags)` and keep it in my `<td></td>` html tags. This works fine, but I would like to use [Grid.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com) for filtering and sorting other columns.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Changes).Columns(columns =>
{
       columns.Add(foo => foo.Name).Sortable(true).SetWidth(110);
       ...
       ...
       ...
       columns.Add(foo => foo.Tags);
}).WithPaging(20)
```

But this (obviously) doesn't work. My guess is I have to use `.RenderValueAs()` method, but I'm running out of ideas. Could you give me an advice on how to do this?

* - tags like the ones below each post here on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

do you have

```
@using GridMvc.Html
```

in the top?

And possibly:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
       columns.Add(foo => foo.Name).Titled("item 1").Sortable(true).SetWidth(110);
       columns.Add(foo => foo.Name).Titled("item 2").Sortable(true).SetWidth(110);
}).WithPaging(10)
```